# Ways to visualise a user journey

Tags: info-visualisation, deliverables, user-journey

I would like some opinions on user journeys and how to present them, specifically to the client. What do you think is the best way to present them and what tools would you use to create them?

Do you have any links to what you consider good examples of user journeys?

Comment: https://medium.com/p/950fcb5d2ebe check this post

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Where appropriate - I've often liked the infographic 3D style user journeys as they really key into the visuals and real world perception - see example on [Wireframes Magazine](http://wireframes.linowski.ca/2009/01/user-journeys/) and also linked article [An introduction to user journeys](http://boxesandarrows.com/an-introduction-to-user-journeys/) on Boxes and Arrows.

[image]

I also love this [snapshot on flikr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/petalpie/5050998310/) by user [tgod](http://www.flickr.com/photos/petalpie/) from the [LUX](http://lux.org.uk/) redesign project (*not sure if I should really be including the image here*) - it's clean, simple, but presents (and therefore identifies visually with) the persona, illustrates the flow nicely, uses colour themed stages, utilizes intensity of colour for an added dimension, and with thought bubbles where relevant - a really nice example!

[image]

Both these examples are good alternatives to the more common rather dull and boxy flow chart style presentations that clients especially have a hard time digesting (and the rest of the team for that matter). These examples are both useful, engaging and, more importantly, likely to be read.

Both these were created with [omnigraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/), but you could use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) (free), [Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html) or similar for equally scalable quality output.

Comment: Thanks Roger, Some great examples. I really like the isometric example. I think for the scenario I'm looking at that type of approach gives enough detail while also giving a bit of visual appeal instead of the traditional flow diagrams we use.

Comment: and good for personas too

Answer (score 6):

I have had a couple of user journey examples included in the last talk I gave entitled [Some Things You Can't Wireframe](http://www.slideshare.net/wdbecvar/some-things-you-cant-wireframe).

You'll find the slides, and below that the links to the websites where I got the examples from - including the [Lego Wheel](http://experiencematters.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/legowheel.png), [Home Theatre](http://blogs.hbr.org/cs/2010/11/using_customer_journey_maps_to.html) and [Service Design](http://files.thisisservicedesignthinking.com/tisdt_cujoca.pdf). Hope it's useful!

Here's one of the screenshots: the Lego Wheel for a flight from London to New York as found at [Customer Experience Matters](http://experiencematters.wordpress.com/2009/03/03/legos-building-block-for-good-experiences/):

[image]

Comment: +1 But I hope you don't mind - I made this answer a bit easier to digest.

Answer (score -1):

Speaking of tools, check out [UXPressia](http://uxpressia.com)  - online service to create awesome-looking customer journey maps (and even Personas now). You can export maps in png or pdf which seems to be the answer to your problem. UXPressia also offers a variety of templates so you can grab the one that fits your tweak it and create a map in a matter of minutes.

Comment: As it is this reads more like an ad than an answer to the question. Could you rephrase this?